# JAXB: Severity 2 events (fatal errors) instead of severity 1 events (errors) during XML validation

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

During XML validation against an XSD file using JAXB I seem to get severity 2 events (fatal errors) instead of severity 1 events (errors).

To check my impression I used an exact copy of the code posted in the blog entry [JAXB and Marshal/Unmarshal Schema Validation at Blaise Doughan's Blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html), using the Unmarshal Demo. Instead of the three severity 1 events shown at that blog I get severity 2 events. Here is my output:

```
EVENT
SEVERITY:  2
MESSAGE:  cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringMaxSize5'.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/.../workspace/JAXBTest/input.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25; cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringMaxSize5'.
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  2
    COLUMN NUMBER:  25
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  null
    NODE:  null
    URL:  file:/C:/.../workspace/JAXBTest/input.xml

EVENT
SEVERITY:  2
MESSAGE:  cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/.../workspace/JAXBTest/input.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25; cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  2
    COLUMN NUMBER:  25
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  null
    NODE:  null
    URL:  file:/C:/.../workspace/JAXBTest/input.xml

EVENT
SEVERITY:  2
MESSAGE:  cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone-number'. No child element is expected at this point.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/.../workspace/JAXBTest/input.xml; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 19; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone-number'. No child element is expected at this point.
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  5
    COLUMN NUMBER:  19
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  null
    NODE:  null
    URL:  file:/C:/.../workspace/JAXBTest/input.xml
```

In my own project I want to collect all invalid points of an XML file. So far this doesn't work since I get severity 2 events for most invalid parts of the XML file, even if there is just a value out of its specified range.

**How do I get the expected severity 1 classification for simple XML validation errors? Is there any mechanism that changes the classification of XML validation events in JAXB?**

On the other hand, I could configure my exception handler to continue even if there is a fatal error, but I don't think this is a good idea.

Originally, I wanted to use the ValidationEventCollector of JAXB, but it usually collects only the first event since it stops when it gets a fatal error (severity 2) which is the case with nearly every validation problem as far as I could see.

I'm using Java 1.8.0 and I have had this behaviour on a windows system as well as on a mac.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post the code example I used or just the link to the code. I used the link. I hope tis is ok.

Comment: Any Ideas on this problem? Do you get severity 1 or severity 2 errors with the code example from the link in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying for days to find a way to do that, with no avail. Apparently JAXB folks thought that distinguishing fatal errors from errors in an unmarshal context is not useful. So they decided to map errors to fatal errors:

```java
validator.setErrorHandler(new FatalAdapter(getContext()));
```

And the `FatalAdapter` in question:

```java
/**
 * Maps an error to a fatal error.
 * 
 * @author Kohsuke Kawaguchi
 */
public class FatalAdapter implements ErrorHandler {

[...]

    public void error (SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        core.fatalError(exception);
    }

[...]

}
```

**And the information is now lost.**

I even tried using reflection (I know, bad) to fix this at runtime, but the class is instantiated as a local variable inside a method so I can't reach it. A patch is required for this I think.

I eventually ended up doing a preemptive validation before unmarshalling (and reading the input twice).

---

**EDIT**: I might have found out a way. But is a very VERY dirty workaround. If you inspect the stacktrace of the SAXParseException you receive with the validation event you will notice:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 1; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
```

I used the origin of the exception to determine the severity (fatal errors coming from the "fatalError" method and errors coming from the "error" method).

Bad, I know. But as I said, **very very dirty workaround**.